# Dynamics AX 2009 X++: Fix id in modification of application after import version control

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

How to fix **ID** in modification of application?

This problem will appear after changing database, and importing version control with set parameters:

- cover by system tables and shared
- does not search for existing records
- index update during import

The problem is that on a few tables will show an error message:

> sql database reported an error

Answer (score 0):

Do a [full synchronize](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa548671.aspx) of the database.

Beware, it may remove then reinsert fields or tables, if the id changed.

Comment: You have to be more specific on what error you get. Try to look in System Administration\Inqueries\Database\SQL Statement trace log.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact issue, you can write a job to manually fix it.

This is a more advanced task, so if you're not totally comfortable with it, I'd try Jan's approach.

```
ReleaseUpdateDB::changeTableId(...);
ReleaseUpdateDB::changeFieldId(...);
ReleaseUpdateDB::change* stuff
```

Also, Martin wrote a job that does a lot of it for you. I had to tweak it myself before:

http://dev.goshoom.net/en/2011/11/id-change/